# How to use nginx with Kubernetes (GKE) and Google HTTPS load balancer

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We make use of Ingress to create HTTPS load balancers that forward directly to our (typically nodejs) services. However, recently we have wanted more control of traffic in front of nodejs which the Google load balancer doesn't provide.

- Standardised, custom error pages
- Standard rewrite rules (e.g redirect http to https)
- Decouple pod readinessProbes from load balancer health checks (so we can still serve custom error pages when there are no healthy pods).

We use nginx in other parts of our stack so this seems like a good choice, and I have seen several examples of nginx being used to front services in Kubernetes, typically in one of two configurations.

- An nginx container in every pod forwarding traffic directly to the application on localhost.
- A separate nginx Deployment & Service, scaled independently and forwarding traffic to the appropriate Kubernetes Service.

What are the pros/cons of each method and how should I determine which one is most appropriate for our use case?

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Vincent H, I'd suggest pipelining the Google HTTPS Load Balancer to an nginx ingress controller.

As you've mentioned, this can scale independently; have it's own health checks; and you can standardise your error pages.

We've achieved this by having a single `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"` ingress object, which has a default backend of our nginx ingress controller. All our other ingress objects are annotated with `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`.

We're using the controller documented here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx. With a [custom `/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/dd7f8b4a972d9c7346da2b37419ff3529d3b38d0/controllers/nginx/configuration.md) allowing complete control over the ingress.

> For complete transparency, we haven't (yet) setup custom error pages in the nginx controller, however the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/dd7f8b4a972d9c7346da2b37419ff3529d3b38d0/examples/customization/custom-errors/nginx) appears straight forward.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the implementation details? I am facing the same challenge.

Comment: Interesting, thank-you. Is there a reason you use the GCE HTTP load balancer in front of nginx, and not a TCP only network load balancer?

Comment: We're running Kubernetes as GKE, therefore the integration was setup for ourselves in the cluster already. Honestly, it was just the easiest thing to do for us at the time and works well for our needs.

Comment: @Hawky4s Sorry, didn't see any notifications about your request. Did you get anywhere in the end or do you still need more info?

Comment: @Tribal I was able to come up with a solution based on having a service for provisioning a GCE loadbalancer which redirects the L4 traffic to an Nginx Ingress deployment on some nodes.

Answer (score 1):

One of the requirements listed is that you want to decouple the pod readinessProbes so you can serve custom error pages. If you are adding a nginx container to every pod this isn't possible. Then the pod will be restarted when one of the containers in the pod fails to adhere to the liveness/readiness probes. Personally I also prefer to decouple as much as you can so you can scale independent pods, assign custom machine types if needed, and it saves you some resources by starting only the amount of nginx instances you really need (mostly memory).

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. Thanks for helping clarify my thinking around this - I find myself looking for validation of a lot of stuff from people that have done this before. Mostly to check I'm not missing something really obvious with the way I'm designing these system. :)